# Getting Server error while using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting the following error while trying to add model and display data in view using Asp.NET mvc2 application.

**Error:**

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MvcInputScreen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Source Error:**

> Line 158:
>       Line 159:    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]
>       Line 160:    public class views_customer_displaycustomer_aspx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {
>       Line 161:
>       Line 162:        private static bool @__initialized;
>
> Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\36f3c2d6\5d16a5e9\App_Web_displaycustomer.aspx.90494039.kvpkqitq.0.cs    Line: 160
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> Show Complete Compilation Source:

The following are my code files.

**CustomerController.cs:**

```
namespace Mydemo.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Customer/

        public ViewResult DisplayCustomer()
        {
            Customer objCustomer = new Customer();
            objCustomer.Id = 12;
            objCustomer.CustomerCode = "1001";
            objCustomer.Amount = 90.34;

            return View("DisplayCustomer", objCustomer);
        }

    }
}
```

**Customer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Mydemo.Controllers
{
    class Customer
    {
        private string _Code;
        private string _Name;
        private double _Amount;

        public string Code
        {
            set
            {
                _Code = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _Code;
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }

        public double Amount
        {
            set
            {
                _Amount = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _Amount;
            }
        }

        public string CustomerCode { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DisplayCustomer.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcInputScreen.Models.Customer>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>DisplayCustomer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    The customer id is <%= Model.Id %><br />

The customer Code is <%= Model.CustomerCode %><br />

<% if (Model.Amount > 100) {%>
This is a priveleged customer
<% } else{ %>
This is a normal customer
<%} %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to resolve this error.As i am also new to ASP.NET i want to know how to set route file here that means suppose i have 3 view files (i.e-index,create,details) i want to set any one file at any time such a way that if i am typing only `http://localhost:port no` that page will come directly.

Comment: Where do you get this error ?\

Comment: @Mairaj : While running this app by this url `http://localhost:5749/customer/DisplayCustomer`.

Comment: Where is `MvcInputScreen` being used ?

Comment: @Mairaj : to create strongly typed view.

Comment: Please show that code also.

Comment: @ Mairaj : i checked the option create strong typed view at the time of creating view ` DisplayCustomer` which is explained above..

Comment: Can u show code of your models where `MvcInputScreen` is being used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80563/discussion-between-satya-and-mairaj-ahmad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is expecting `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcInputScreen.Models.Customer>"` while your `customer` class is in `MyDemo.Controller` namespace so you should change it to System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage".

> Also i would recommend you to change namespace of your `Model` classes
>   from  `Mydemo.Controllers` to `Mydemo.Models`.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the error message:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MvcInputScreen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> `Line 160:    public class views_customer_displaycustomer_aspx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcInputScreen.Models.Customer>, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {`

The error is in line 160 because your `Customer`-class doesn't reside in the namespace `MvcInputScreen.Models.Customer` but in `Mydemo.Controllers.Customer`.

So just edit the corresponding line in `DisplayCustomer.aspx`.